# Add a class for odd columns with eq greater than 3 in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how do I add classes for Odd columns in a data table whose eq is greater than 3 ?? this is the code which i tried out, and its giving the class to the tr. Is there any neat way to achieve it ??

```
$('.dataTable tr').each(function() {
console.log($(this))
if ( $(this).children('td:odd') || $(this).children('td:gt(3)') ) {
$(this).addClass('oddColumn');
// how do I access the td element here ??
}
});
```

Comment: Do you want to add the class to all columns in an odd row or do you want to add the class to odd columns in all rows? Or odd columns in odd rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$('tr td:nth-child(2n+5)').addClass('c');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AQdY8/

Note that jQuery's `nth-child` selector matches [the CSS version](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo):

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has `an+b-1` siblings **before** it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of `n`, and has a parent element.

A side effect of this is that it [indexes from 1 rather than 0](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) as the other jQuery selectors:

> Because jQuery's implementation of `:nth-child(n)` is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of `n` is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1.

Comment: wow.. cool, never knew that there could be an operation possible in the col :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dataTable tr td:odd').addclass
$('.dataTable tr td:gt(3)').addclass
```

Though I think the classes will get added twice for gt(3) and odd

Comment: this wont work, first i have to loop thru each table rows with odd index and greater than 4 index... :-(

Comment: Yeah the answer by @mu is too short is amazing

Answer (score 0):

I want to target specific columns and change the style.

I have a table with icons in the first column and the last two columns. Then I have a variable number of data columns in the middle. Depending to the table width, I want to show either the first 5 or 10 data columns and hide the rest. But I need the icons to show all the time.

```
<tr>
<td><a href="#" class="icon-magnifyingGlass">View</a></td>
<td class="dataCol">Seq</td>
<td class="dataCol">Code</td>
<td class="dataCol">Date</td>
<td class="dataCol">Comment</td>
<td class="dataCol">Int</td>
<td class="dataCol">Date</td>
<td class="dataCol">User</td>
<td class="dataCol">Seq</td>
<td class="dataCol">Code</td>
<td class="dataCol">Date</td>
<td class="dataCol">Comment</td>
<td class="dataCol">Int</td>
<td class="dataCol">Date</td>
<td class="dataCol">User</td>
<td><a href="#" class="icon-pencil">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="#" class="icon-x">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

I tried using the nth-child() selector to target specific columns 1, 2-6, the next to last column nth-child(-n-2) and the last column (last-child). However, older browsers like IE6, IE7 and IE8 do not support nth-child(). Although I am using jquery and moderinzer to support CSS3, it still did not work for me.

My work around was to manually put classes on the specific columns I was targeting, such as class="dataCol". Then I was able to use the gt() selector to show the first five data columns and hide the rest, while keeping the first and last two icon columns visible.

> ```
> $("#example tr").each(function(){
>      $(this).find(".dataCol:gt(4)").css("display","none");
>      });
> ```

The result is I got the 5 data columns, plus the three icon columns to show and the rest are hidden.

Thanks for all the posts, it was very helpful.